# Ubuntu php5-fpm unix socket

Tags: php, nginx

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and installed php5-fpm and I want to configure nginx. I want to use unix sockets instead of tcp sockets but I couldn't find the

```
 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

I have looked also

```
/tmp/php5-fpm.sock
```

Where is php5-fpm.sock file? I also tried

```
locate php5-fpm.sock
```

but I couldn't find anything. 
Note: php5-fpm is working . I have started as a service
http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/wordpress-on-nginx/
http://blog.nas-admin.org/?p=25

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the default configuration *before* 12.10 Quantal, PHP FPM is set to listen on TCP port 9000 on address 127.0.0.1. This can be changed in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Look for the line:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

and change it to something like:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

After doing so, restart PHP FPM:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

(note: `reload` is broken on Oneiric as it sends a HUP signal to php5-fpm which is wrong. It's fixed in Precise by sending USR2, [bugreport](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=645934)).

Note: as mentioned by @SpamapS (palingdrome :D), newer releases use Unix sockets by default, not the tcp socket. See [this Launchpad comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/900620/comments/11), it got changed in 12.10 Quantal.

Comment: Just a note, on precise, php5-fpm actually runs on a socket by default. ;)

Comment: @SpamapS I don't think so, the changelog does not mention anything. Just to be sure, I checked the php5-fpm .deb package for version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 and it still contains `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`. Perhaps you've previously changed this and upgraded while keeping the conffiles?

Comment: Well no, I submitted the change to Debian, and they merged it, but only to the PHP 5.4 packages. I actually mistakenly set the bug status on http://pad.lv/900620 , so thanks for the heads up, set it back to Triaged. We'll pick it up on the next merge from Debian.

Comment: In 14.04, it appears to use a UNIX socket by default, so things must have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this method is old and will no longer work
.
**OLD**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Now a days you need to use

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

In place of restart you may also use; start, stop and reload.