# LEMP Stack "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden error

Tags: server, permissions, nginx

I'm setting up a LEMP stack on Google Compute Engine to run Magento 1.9. I've configured the server with PHP7/Nginx with Ubuntu 14.04. When I run the Magento setup, halfway through it redirects from `downloader.php` to `downloader/` and I get a `403 Forbidden` error.

The nginx log then says this: `*323 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden`.

I've Googled around and came up with some possible solutions [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114076/ubuntu-php5-fpm-unix-socket/114086#114086), but I've checked the `www.conf` and it seems to listen to php-fpm already. Any ideas on where to look for the cause?

Comment: Was it so simple to forget the magento nginx config? Gonna find that  out right now!

Comment: Yep. That seemed to do the trick. It solved this error, there's more though, but I'll work through them! Thanks for the point in the right direction @ThomasWard!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, so you can mark this question as resolved by accepting the answer.  Your Magneto specific issues should be posted separately, because it's different errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `nginx` configuration issue, and not a PHP/Magento one.

NGINX is trying to do a directory listing and not passing things properly to Magento in the backend I think.

That's why it gives the error it does - it can't do a directory listing of the docroot because you haven't enabled that functionality, and you likely wouldn't need to if you hand it off to Magento properly and have correct redirects, processing, etc. in the NGINX side of things.